# To convert this formula in to raw python without any library

Tags: python

logloss=−1∗1nΣforeachYt,Ypred(Ytlog10(Ypred)+(1−Yt)log10(1−Ypred))

How do I write this formula in raw python without any library?

My code:

```
def logloss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss=0
    for i,j in range (len(y_true),len(y_pred)):
            loss+=((y_true[i],y_pred[j]*(y_true(math.log10(y_pred[j]))+((1-y_true[i])*math.log10(1-y_pred[j])))
    loss=-1*(1/len(y_true))*loss
    return loss
```

Error : Invalid syntax.

Comment: Hey, even though your question got edited already, make sure that you dont just paste your code. You can use three of those "`" with a line break, then paste your code and then close the code block again with three "`".

Answer (score 2):

you're just missing some parentheses, try something like this:

```
import math


def logloss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 0
    for i, j in range(len(y_true), len(y_pred)):
        loss += ((y_true[i], y_pred[j] * (y_true(math.log10(y_pred[j])) + (
                    (1 - y_true[i]) * math.log10(1 - y_pred[j])))))
    loss = -1 * (1 / len(y_true)) * loss
    return loss
```

I'd offer you to split up this long line to make it more readable and make it easier to find problems.

also, I believe that the function you actually want is (assuming that `y_pred` and `y_true` have the same length, which they should if IIUC from a ML point of view):

```
import math


def logloss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        loss += y_true[i] * math.log10(y_pred[i]) + \
                (1-y_true[i]) * math.log10(1-y_pred[i])
    loss = -1 * (1 / len(y_true)) * loss
    return loss
```

I assume you are doing this for some machine learning, I'd suggest you first learn more python before going on to heavy topics like NNs.